# CPLEX Python API Manual with References

Tags: python, cplex, cplex-python-api

I am currently attempting to code a model using the Python API.

However, the IBM Site seems to not have one that is similar in formating and content depth such as those for C++ or Java (examples and quick starter chapters).

I am hazarding a guess that it might have been taken down for various reasons.

Thus, may I ask if anyone possesses and is able to share a copy of it which is in PDF format?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want the [matrix oriented python  API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/help.html) or [docplex API](http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/) ?

For docplex, some very simple examples at https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/

Comment: This information can also be found in README.md in the python subdirectory of the CPLEX installation folder. Official docplex examples can be found [here](http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/samples.html).

Comment: Dear Dr Fleischer and Dalmeijer, thank you for your replies, I last used CPLEX alongside its Java API around a decade ago. Thus, I guess I am outdated. Please correct me if I am wrong: tbe old manual seems to have broken up into both the matrix oriented and docplex format. The former being a detailed indexed repository of commands while the latter comprises examples to get one up to speed via using various data types alongside methods to extract them for creation of objectives and constraints.

Comment: Hi, you may still use java to call cplex. You may also use OPL, C++ and many other ways. In python I recommend the high level API docplex. Many links in https://medium.com/@AlainChabrier/decision-optimization-education-a50cada93856

Comment: Dear Dr Fleischer, I have previously used OPL only for prototyping purposes as it was previously unable to handle large sized problems. I understand that things have improved dramatically since then. Thus, I wouid like to enquire if it is able to handle problem sizes that are similar to those of the API. i am.comsidering Python as it is not strongly typed like Java, which is verbose in nature, alongside other programming decorum which mist be strictly adhered.

Comment: Hi, indeed you have many options https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/which-aml-gpl-do-you-use-call-cplex-alex-fleischer/ I tend to prefer OPL. And then you may call OPL from Java, C++, .NET or python

Comment: Dear Dr Fleischer, wow, python has grown, while OPL is still leading the pack. But, I however, still need your kind inputs on the critical question as to whether OPL is now capable of handling large problem instances which  previously APIs were only capable of handling. Thank you!

Comment: Yes OPL is able to handle large instances. In https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/optimization-aka-prescriptive-analytics-should-we-write-fleischer/?trk=pulse_spock-articles I discuss pros and cons between AML and GPL , OPL vs Python